# How can I save an Inkscape drawing so it can be opened in CorelDRAW without losing layer information?

Tags: inkscape, corel-draw

Is there a way to save an Inkscape drawing so the layer information will not be removed?
When I save the drawing as plain SVG and try to open it again in Inkscape, all layers are gone.

Comment: SVGs don't really support layers. One of the differences between an *Inkscape* SVG and a *plain* SVG while saving is that an *Inkscape* SVG can include some group level tags specific to Inkscape to tell Inkscape to treat that group as a layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. PDF does also not support Layers. So there is no way to convert Inkscape SVG to Coreldraw ?

Comment: A quick Google search turned up [this script](https://github.com/jbohren/beamerscape) that lets you export individual SVG layers as PDF files. Sort of a hassle, but might be a temporary workaround if you need something urgently. Other recommendations (not tested) include grouping the objects in each layer, moving them all the one layer (but still grouped), and exporting as a plain SVG. Haven't had a chance to test either of these, hence I'm adding this as a comment instead of an answer. Will try to find some time later to test them out.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I came across this question, and it's a shame it doesn't have an answer (especially since you *have* found a workaround!). Would you mind posting it as an answer? That way people can identify it easier, and also upvote it.

Comment: I have no solution for this. My Main problem was, that I have so many layers, that Inkscape slowed down. So I thought to try in CorelDraw. Meanwhile I have several Inkscape Drawings and compute the merged by a selfmade programm.

Comment: FWIW, The PDF format does support layers. A possible work-around for this would be to select the contents of each layer in Inkscape and group it before saving, then in CorelDraw, create a new layer for each group and then ungroup it.

Comment: SVG supports layers. They are just called “groups.” So you make a group tag and give it an id of “layer 1” and another group tag and give it an id of “layer 2,” etc.

Comment: @WillAdams a layer in an Inkscape drawing is actually *already* a group. If you you inspect the drawing's XML, you can see that it has a special namespaced layer attribute so that Inkscape knows to treat it like a layer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `DXF`-format preserves layer-information. Although many other information is lost throught this way (f.e. fillcolors), and paths might have to be reconnected.

So the answer to this question (*preserving layer-information*) would be, to save and open as `DXF`, although it's not very satifying (*other information is lost*).

(*Unfortunately I do not have enough Rep to comment on questions, otherwise I would have done that, instead of writing an answer*)