How best can I import Inkscape file to coreldraw
I know Inkscape saves files in .SVG by default, I also know coreldraw works with SVG well for vectors.
However, I noticed that everything breaks as soon as I import from inkscape into coreldraw.
What am I doing wrong here?

left (Inkscape), Right (coreldraw)

Please provide more details to cover "everything breaks."

I have updated the post with an image for clarity.

related https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/how-can-i-save-an-inkscape-drawing-so-it-can-be-opened-in-coreldraw-without-losi

already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879299/export-svg-from-inkscape-to-corel-draw

Yes, I had gone through the thread, but it wasn't resolved.

Try saving as a PDF instead, and import that into CorelDraw.  Another possibility is make sure to save a "Plain SVG" in Inkscape. Inkscape's default SVG format contains Inkscape specific XML which can confuse other applications.
